# Error inserting into a database from a form

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hi I'm trying to insert some data from a form into my database but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not getting any errors from the mysql_error() and I can't for the life of my figure out what could be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

The code is outputting "Unsuccessful! Test 9".

Here's my form

```
<form method="post" action="blog_add_posts.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

<fieldset>
    <legend>Add Blog Posts</legend>
    <label>Title: <input type="text" name="title" /></label>
    <label>Body: <input type="text" name="body" /></label>
</fieldset>
<br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit Post" />
</form>
```

Here's my PHP (I've hid the define statements for security reasons)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    define('DB_NAME', '(Hiding For Security)');
    define('DB_USER', '(Hiding For Security)');
    define('DB_PW', '(Hiding For Security)');
    define('DB_HOST', '(Hiding For Security)');

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PW);

    if(!$link){
        die('Test Connection Failed 1: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

    if(!$db_selected){
        die('Test Connection Failed 1: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $title);
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $body = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $body);
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO 'phpmy1_belairfinishing_com'.'Blog' (Post_ID, Post_Title,     Post_Date, Post_Body) VALUES (NULL, '$title', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$body')";

    if(mysqli_real_query($link, $sqlInsert)){
        echo "<p> Successful! </p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p> Unsuccessful! Test 11 </p>";
    }

    $newrecord = "Successfully Added To Database";

    mysqli_close($link);

} //End of ISSET if statement

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing mysql_ and mysqli_

For example you have:

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PW);
```

but then you use:

```
if(mysqli_real_query($link, $sqlInsert)){
```

You should use one or the other but you cannot mix them together like this

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even notice that. +1

Comment: I didn't either. This fixed the problem thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Post" />
```

Change your HTML code to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit Post" />
```

and remove

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
```

And tell me how it goes.

Comment: Try echoing the query you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you need to have your PHP variables outside the string, otherwise they will be parsed as text (ex: "$title") instead of the actual values of the variable:

```
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO 'phpmy1_belairfinishing_com'.'Blog' (Post_ID, Post_Title, Post_Date, Post_Body) VALUES (NULL, '".$title."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '".$body."')";
```

Also in your form you need to have `value` so there is data to get:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="" />
<input type="text" name="body" value="" />
```

This makes them blank at the start, make sure to type into them before hitting submit.

Along with this as **@bhttoan** pointed out. You need to make sure you are doing `mysqli` for all your functions and not `mysql` interlaced with `mysqli`.

Comment: It might not matter, but try removing the single quotes from your relation: `..INTO phpmy1_belairfinishing_com.Blog (Po..`. Otherwise you are not getting the table properly or the values given are not allowed to go into this table.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I'm still getting the same error. Do you think it could be a problem selecting that table from the database?

Comment: Check your database for the schema `phpmy1_belairfinishing_com` and a relation inside `Blog`. And also see if you can run the Query in your database (give some test values for `$body` and `$title`), and see if that works.

Comment: I was able to insert a record into the Blog table from my myPhPAdmin panel. This is the SQL line it used
INSERT INTO `phpmy1_belairfinishing_com`.`Blog` (`Post_ID`, `Post_Title`, `Post_Date`, `Post_Body`) VALUES (NULL, 'Test Post', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Test Post');

Comment: @TimothyMcGee Then echo out `$body` and `$title` in PHP (or the entire query). Do they have a value that you gave them?

Comment: When echoing both $body and $title out I only get "" "". When I use the entire query I get the same "" where $body and $title are.

Comment: @TimothyMcGee You need to add the `value` attribute in your input items (see edit). It's possible you already placed blanks in the database and it's not allowing you to place a duplicate.

Comment: <input type="text" value="" name="title" /> is how my new input tags look, $title and $body still echo to "". Also checked my database there's currently no records.

Comment: @TimothyMcGee Did you enter text into the value? For example for testing do : `value="Hello"`. You need to type the text into the form if you did not do so.

Comment: I've been manually inputting them into the form fields. I just tried doing value="test post" and still getting nothing inside either variable.

Comment: @TimothyMcGee Your `$link` is made with `mysql`, but the escape strings are called with `mysqli`, you can't use those together. Do `mysqli_connect(...)`

Comment: Changing the mysql to mysqli fixed it! Thanks a ton for all the help.